# SOQL query with subquery

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, soql

I'm having trouble getting the results I want from a Salesforce/Apex/SOQL query.

**I want:** A list of Contact objects containing only contacts who are CampaignMembers of a set of campaigns; and they should have the data from that Campaign member easily accessible.
(my eventual goal is a VF page with a list of all Contacts connected to any of these campaigns with a grid indicating their status for each campaign.)

**These work:**

```
Campaign[] cams = [SELECT id, name 
                     FROM Campaign 
                    WHERE parentid = '70170000000LRIe'];  
System.debug(cams);  
// returns ~4 Campaign objects

CampaignMember[] cmembers = [SELECT id, status, contactid, campaignid 
                               FROM CampaignMember 
                              WHERE campaignid in :cams];  
System.debug(cmembers);  
// returns about 40 CampaignMember objects.
```

### Here's my problem:

```
Contact[] members = [SELECT id, firstname, lastname, 
                            (SELECT id, status, comment__c, campaignid 
                               FROM Contact.CampaignMembers 
                              WHERE campaignid in :cams) 
                       FROM Contact];  
System.debug(members);  
// contains ALL Contacts in the DB, but I wanted filtered results.
System.debug(members[x].CampaignMembers);
// this is a contact I've verified has a qualifying CampaignMember, but the list is empty.
// UPDATE: CampaignMembers are now being returned, not sure what changed...
```

---

1. <del>Why aren't any CampaignMember objects being returned from the subquery?</del>
2. **Why isn't the Contact list being filtered?  (well, obviously b/c there's no WHERE clause in it, but what WHERE clause provides what I want?)**

I know I could do this by doing the CampaignMember query on its own and looping through it to prep a Contact query, but that seems like a lot of extra processing when a subquery should work.

Thanks!

---

**Update**

The CampaignMember objects are now showing up - oddly - I must have fixed some small typo without noticing (and yes, they're returning multiple columns and that seems to be fine).

I still can't figure out how to filter the Contact query, though...

Comment: SQL subqueries in the SELECT aren't allowed to return more than one column

Comment: Why you use a SQL subquery there? You can make a join query between the 2 tables!! As Omg Ponies said, the subquery on the select just can return 1 column per subquery!!

Comment: This is salesforce **SOQL**, not SQL.  There is no JOIN keyword in SOQL - you can only traverse relationships using subqueries (which do return more than one column).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use a semi-join on contacts to filter the contacts to the set you want, something like this

```
[select id, firstname, lastname, 
     (select id, status, comment__c, campaignid from CampaignMembers)
     from contact where id in 
          (select contactId from campaignMember where campaignId in :cams];
```

Another option would be to drive from campaignMmeber instead.

```
[select contact.id, contact.firstname, contact.lastname, 
  status, comment__c, campaignId from campaignMembers 
  where contactId !='' and  campaignId in :cams];
```

Comment: Looks promising -- i won't have a chance to try for a few days but will check back.  Thanks!

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks.   I ended up going w/ the first option, which is just one query (!) for governor limits, and autogroups the CampaignMembers by Contact which is convenient.

Comment: Can you tell me that how to create campaign through ZKSfORCE api?

Comment: Can we update objects like these in Apex??
Does it Returns Sobject or contact